# Как установить beesu на CentOS 8?

Tags: linux, install, xfce

Поставил `CentOS 8`, но в нем нет пакета `beesu` или `gksu`. Пытался отдельно ставить rpm пакеты `beesu` из `Fedora` - безрезультатно. Раньше стоял `CentOS 7`, там у меня был ярлык на рабочем столе для *Root terminal*, примерно такой:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=beesu exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator
Icon=gksu-root-terminal
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;X-XFCE;X-Xfce-Toplevel;
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
Name=Terminal Emulator
Comment=Use the command line
```

Что следует использовать взамен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `CentOS 8`, и также в `Debian 10`, можно использовать `Policykit` для этой цели. Вместо `beesu`, используйте **`pkexec`** - в гафическом режиме поведение такое же: он запрашивает пароль перед запуском программы.

Создайте собственный файл `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/custom.policy`, примерно так:

```xml
<policyconfig>
  <vendor>Custom</vendor>

  <action id="exo-open">
    <description>Run as root</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to run as root.</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>no</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/exo-open</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
  </action>

  <!-- another actions -->

</policyconfig>
```

Затем обновите ярлык на рабочем столе для *Root terminal*, примерно так:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=pkexec exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator
Icon=gksu-root-terminal
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;X-XFCE;X-Xfce-Toplevel;
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
Name=Terminal Emulator
Comment=Use the command line
Path=
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем так сложно?

В терминале:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/gksudo
```

С помощью любого редактора (`mcedit`, `gedit`, `xed`) вставляем строчку:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY $@
```

и сохраняем её.

```
sudo chmod 755 gksudo /usr/local/bin/gksudo
```

хочется `gksu` - по схеме создаем файл `gksu`:

```
sudo mcedit /usr/share/applications/rootterminal.desktop
```

Содержание файла `rootterminal.desktop`. Например, так:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Root Terminal
Comment=Run Terminal as Root
Icon=gksu-root-terminal
Exec=gksudo x-terminal-emulator
Type=Application
Categories=System;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
```

Сохраняем. Пользуемся. Ярлык будет в меню `System/Системные`.